# Manifold and the topology of $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, general-relativity

i'm starting to study manifold in order to understand Einstein's relativity but there is something I don't understand.
A manifold $M$ is defined as being locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. Homeomorphisms can be defined in terms of how they map open sets, namely an homemorphism $f$ and its inverse $f^{-1}$ have to map open sets to open sets. 
The question is: Are the topology of $M$ and $\Bbb R^n$ the same? 
Because then I put a distance in $\Bbb R^n$ and the distance will be locally the same in $M$. So since a distance induce a topology I think they must be the same.

Can I say that if $R^n$ is a metric space and $M$ is a manifold on this metric space then: The metric induce a topology on $R^n$, the metric of $R^n$ induce a metric on $M$ and so a topology?

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908727/why-is-there-no-natural-metric-on-manifolds).

Comment: The metrics won't be the same globally: think of a solid donut sitting in 3-space. The metric inside the solid donut between points $P$ and $Q$ is given by measuring the length of the shortest curve joining $P$ and $Q$ (lying a bit here). Imagine that $P$ and $Q$ are on opposite sides of the donut hole. Their path won't be a straight line!